# Highcharts with inverted y-axis, but not inverted data?

Tags: highcharts, axis

Is it possible to invert the y-axis, but not the data? I have a ranking which should start with 1 at the top, not at the bottom, but the columns should stay just normal.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good easy direct way to do it (afaik).

There are a variety of approaches you could take, however.

This example uses a reversed axis and stacked columns:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/301/

```
stacking:'normal',
```

It relies on adding a second series that is the difference between your value and the max, which means you must also specify a y axis max.

I left the second series a light grey so you can see them, but you can set their opacity to 0 so that they are invisible.

Other options might include doing some calculations on the y axis label formatter to display the axis labels as you want without having to touch the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reversed yAxis, and column series, where each point will have `y` and `low` values, where `low` values are the same as the lowest number. See: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/303/

```
var max = 10;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
title: {
    text: 'Chart Title'
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: max,
    tickInterval: 2,
    reversed: true
},
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [{
        y: 1,
        low: max
    }, {
        y: 3,
        low: max
    }, {
        y: 6,
        low: max
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts provides an option for this called reversed setting it true will do the work for you.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversed

```
reversed: true
```

here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bmbhD/

Comment: Thanks. But that command reverses the graph too. And that's something I don't want.

Comment: you wanted the y-axis labels such that the highest value will be nearer to the origin right.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps my question was not clear? I said: "Is it possible to invert the y-axis, but not the data?" Should perhaps be: "... but not the graph". So, from bottom to top it should not read 0, 1, 2, ... but 10, 9, 8, ... But the column graph should stay as it is.

Comment: since the plot of any graph/chart starts from the co-ordinates (0,0). when you use a column chart it will be reversed.